# LNK2001 and LNK2019 error during VS2008 (or VS2010) upgrade from VS2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

I am attempting to upgrade an old VC6 solution to VS2010.  Everything compiles fine (after a few code changes to handle some VC++ changes), but it refuses to link.  I have 6 static libraries -- all set to "Use MFC in a Shared DLL" and "Not Using ATL" -- Unicode character set, and one Application (.EXE) set to "Use Standard Windows Libraries" and "Not Using ATL" (also Unicode, of course).  This solution compiles/links fine using Visual Studio 2005 (SP1), but linking fails on both VS2008 and VS2010.  The error messages are predominantly related to "CStringT".  From everything I've researched, I should have seen these CStringT link errors in VS2005 also (that is when CString changed to template class), but as I said, it links fine in VS2005.  I've tried every tip & trick that has been recommended here and elsewhere (i.e. explicitly importing the template class for CStringT in my stdafx.h header), but no luck.  Anyone have any NEW ideas?  I'll paste a sampling of the errors below for reference.  Thanks!

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const & __thiscall SomeExceptionClass::GetErrorMessage(void)const " (?GetErrorMessage@SomeExceptionClass@@QBEABV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ)   

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const & __thiscall SomeExceptionClass::GetErrorMessage(void)const " (?GetErrorMessage@SomeExceptionClass@@QBEABV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const & __thiscall SomeExceptionClass::GetErrorMessage(void)const " (?GetErrorMessage@SomeExceptionClass@@QBEABV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ) referenced in function __catch$?Init@SomeOtherClass@@QAEHPA_W00000@Z$0

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const & __thiscall SomeExceptionClass::GetErrorMessage(void)const " (?GetErrorMessage@SomeExceptionClass@@QBEABV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const & __thiscall SomeExceptionClass::GetErrorMessage(void)const " (?GetErrorMessage@SomeExceptionClass@@QBEABV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const & __thiscall SomeExceptionClass::GetErrorMessage(void)const " (?GetErrorMessage@SomeExceptionClass@@QBEABV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall SomeDatabaseClass::ExecDirect(class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const &)" (?ExecDirect@SomeDatabaseClass@@QAEXABV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall SomeDatabaseClass::ExecDirect(class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const &)" (?ExecDirect@SomeDatabaseClass@@QAEXABV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z)
```

Comment: might have something to do with the 'Treat wchar_t as built-in type' option, see C++->Language options

Answer (score 0):

DUH! That about sums up this solution.  For some strange reason, VS2008 and VS2010 do a incredibly poor job of handling "additional link dependencies" when upgrading an old VC6 project (while VS2005 seems to handle it just fine).  All I was missing was going into Link options in VS2010 (after loading & upgrading my old VC6 workspace/projects) and adding my five static libraries (lib1.lib, lib2.lib, etc.) to the "Additional Dependencies" field (Linker->Input), and then adding my output folder[s] (where those .LIB files are created) to the "Additional Library Directories" field (Linker->General) -- all under Properties for my actual .EXE project, of course.  Boom, now it links like a charm.  I got so sidetracked with the "red herring" of these CString/template upgrade issues (from MSDN articles, etc.), that I completely missed the obvious.  Hope this helps someone down the road.  :)